# Just want to confirm if this request is 100% secure connection

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am writing an iPhone App and I need to securely send an XML request and receive it ALL securely. I think I did it right I just want some confirmation that the below code is all secure.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://secure.site.com/request"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [xml length]];

[req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody: [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (conn)
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

and in the connectionDidFinishLoading..

```
    - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSString *gotXml = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                    length:[webData length] 
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as the URL has https:// in it, the request will be sent securely.

Comment: The message will be sent securely if there is a certificate installed. Whether the certificate is current, expired or self-signed, the https protocol still encrypts the data.